# Maven Release issue while renaming the package name

Tags: maven

We have a project that has dependency on parent project. As per our organization, We have some SLM maven enforcer rules in the parent project.

And I have disabled those rules and renamed the package structure of the project which I want to release through nexus and when I build it locally, it went successful. But when I am trying to do a release in maven prepare stage its throwing the below error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare
```

Comment: Please provide more details, such as the pom.xml for your project, the command you ran and the complete error message and/or stacktrace shown in console ;)

Comment: @Manu - The Error I am facing                                               
 [ERROR]Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project. Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact.  Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request. -> [Help 1]